# Do inductivists and Karl Popper's theory have mutually exclusive ideals? Are they complementary and/or similar in any way?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I can only see they differences between the two and their limitations. Could someone extend my knowledge?

Comment: See [Karl Popper](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/popper/#ProbDema): one of Popper's key theory is the rejection of induction.

Comment: See [Hypothesis testing: Fisher vs. Popper vs. Bayes](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3176/55).

Comment: Popper did oppose the philosophy of inductive theory building, but he did not fully dismiss the Bayesian apparatus. While often opposed, the inductivist and falsificationist approaches can be, and sometimes are, used in a complementary way. Bayesian, in assessing prior "reasonableness" of hypotheses, and Neyman-Pearson's (which implements Popper's directions, to a degree) in testing and passing judgment on them, see [Hypothesis testing: Fisher vs. Popper vs. Bayes](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3176/55).